# Adding control to TextBox (c# / .net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

```
public class TextBoxDerived : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
{
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
 {
   this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Hello"));
 }
}
```

The above code does not seem to do anything?

I was hoping something like

```
Hello
<input type"textbox" />
```

to be rendered in HTML.

Comment: It seems to me that you are going the wrong way about this. There are other ways to achieve this. Why have you chosen this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TextBox` is not a `CompositeControl`, so it's children won't be rendered automatically.

What you could do, for example, is overwriting the `Render` method and manually rendering the control beforehand.

If you want to, as I assume, provide a textbox label and not some literal content, maybe using a `HtmlGenericControl` with a `span` or `div` tag would be more suitable, in order to automatically render escaped text.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    var label = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
    label.InnerText = "Hello";
    label.RenderControl(writer);

    base.Render(writer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I came up with.

If I created a new instance of system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol() (which textbox derives from) all child controls would be added. Can you explain this?

Comment: @maxp Actually, I think I was mistaken about the requirement for `CompositeControl` - by default `WebControl` also renders its child controls. I took a look at the `TextBox Render()` method in Reflector and see that it doesn't actually call `base.Render()` (which would render the child controls), but instead manually renders the begin tag, text and end tag.

Comment: To clarify, I should probably add that having "child" controls wouldn't make sense to solve your problem either way, as a child control would be rendered as a child node within the TextBoxes' <input> tag, which would be illegal anyway.